# unable to connect EC2 instance from browser, also failed to connect via SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

#### From browser

http://assigned_instance.amazonaws.com

Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at assigned_instance.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

#### From terminal### (SSH issue?)

$chmod 700 /home/me

$chmod 400 /home/me/.ec2/pstam-keypair.pem

$ssh -v -i /home/me/.ec2/pstam-keypair.pem ec2-user@assigned_instance.compute-1.amazonaws.com

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0d-fips 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to assigned_instance.amazonaws.com http://1.2.3.4 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ec2/pstam-keypair.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ec2/pstam-keypair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.7 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'assigned_instance.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ec2/pstam-keypair.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

#### Ping

No problem

Comment: Looks like your KEY is wrong, mind if you check it once again? Make the instance that you are trying to connect is actually connected with this private key.

Comment: Here are some more things to think about and a list of information you can provide to make the question clearer: http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to ***re-check*** the assigned **security groups** to the Instance and even ***resetting them for SSH & HTTP access***.

Comment: from Management console, I have the following for port 22 and port 80, are those correct? (NOTE: please edit this comment to see the correct table layout)

0 - 65535 sg-a7a9a8ce (default)
22 (SSH) 0.0.0.0/0 
80 (HTTP) sg-a7a9a8ce

Comment: @tom yes, those ports are correct... did you created a Spot Instance